# Is unsetting is worth on large arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, ram

I am working now with XML imports. Mostly XML files are 6 MB max, so I simply loop through SimpleXML arrays and write appropriate records in database nothing really difficult and no big worries about performance or RAM usage. But one of XML files is different. It is big 145 MB file with 50k+ products.

So i have a few questions:

1) What is better to loop through this file same way I have done with smaller files or get product indexes from small 3MB file and request other information form remote server 50k times? There is no limit on product requests, so i am concerned about performance and RAM usage here.

My guess is that requests is better idea, but I would really want to hear about this from more experienced people.

2) Second question is about RAM usage and performance. I asked other programmer (i am intern) about this and he said that i need to unset this big array after all these operations. Is this truth?

There are ton of information about insetting variables and arrays, but just not about impact on hardware..

Comment: do you want to free memory after processing your xml file ?

Comment: In the end, yes, I want to make this process better optimized for server.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a research on this question on my own I found that using SimpleXML on large XML is not the best idea. XMLReader was stream based xml parser what I was looking for.

Here is quite good resource on this topic in my opinion: http://yashwanthbm.com/parsing-large-xml-documents-in-php/

This answer actually does not answer my questions directly, it just solves a problem.